# Корректно ли использовать частицу "же" в контексте "зато" и "а я"?

Tags: словообразование

Все делали то-то и то-то. Я же не делал ничего.

(А я не делал ничего. Зато я не делал ничего)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Все делали то-то и то-то. Я же не делал ничего.***

Частица ЖЕ в этом тексте является противительным союзом. По значению этот союз несклько отличается от союзов А и ЗАТО.

**ЖЕ**  **I. частица.** 1. Употр. для **смыслового выделения**, подчеркивания значения слова, после которого ставится. На первом же экзамене провалился. **II. союз.** 1. Употр. для **противопоставления** одного предложения другому. Так было ещё вчера, сегодня же всё разительно переменилось.

Таким образом, **союз ЖЕ** имеет значение противопоставления и одновременно **выделения** нужного слова, этим он отличается от противительного союза А, который выражает только противопоставление или сопоставление.

Противительный союз **ЗАТО** также имеет свою специфику. ЗАТО, союз. 1. Употр. при **возместительном** сопоставлении; но в то же время, однако.